# When a user runs docker containers with volume binding, is it possible to restrict to bind other user's volume?

Tags: docker

I want to set the system like

one user cannot bind other user's volume to the user's container.

In this case, all users are in docker group. I want all docker users to bind the directories under their /home/$user to their own container.

It means that userA can bind directories under /home/userA not /home/userB or /home/userC.

Is it possible?

Comment: It's not. And by giving the users access to run docker containers, you're making it very easy for them to gain root on the host machine. If you don't completely trust the users, they shouldn't be allowed to run containers.

Comment: Anyone who can run any `docker` command can bind-mount any directory and run a container with any user.  "Any directory" includes `/` and "any user" includes `root`.  If you're not already giving your users unrestricted sudo access, you shouldn't allow them Docker access either.